# How to add double tap detection to sample app gatt_sensordata_app?

Tags: bluetooth-gatt, movesense, dfu

I am developing an Android app that gets data from Movesense using the GATT profile from the sample app GATT Sensor Data App [here](https://bitbucket.org/movesense/movesense-device-lib/src/master/samples/gatt_sensordata_app/).
I followed the tutorial available [here](http://movesense.com/docs/esw/getting_started/#getting-started-with-sensor-sw-20). Building the app and getting the DFU worked fine. I can get IMU, HR and temperature data with no issues.

Now I'd like add a tap detection feature to my app. I understand that I have to subscribe to 'System/States', but first I need to be able to receive the system state data.
I understand that I need a modified DFU for that, but I don't understand what changes I should make in which files of the gatt_sensordata_app before rebuilding and generating the new DFU.

What changes should I make in order to broadcast /System/State data?

(I usually just deal with Android so apologies for the very basic question.)

I tried adding `#include "system_states/resources.h"` to GATTSensorDataClient.cpp but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Did you managed todo this ?

Comment: Nope, put this feature on hold. If you have the solution, help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Trying as well.  I added the system state resources to the gatt service but still , no data come via gatt. All works fine via the adv bridge.

Comment: I added a bounty but no luck

Comment: @JimmyKane is my answer below something that you're looking for?

Comment: @yet-it-compiles sorry but what answer?

Answer (score 1):

The normal data straming in the gatt_sensordata_app uses the sbem-encoding code that the build process generates when building the firmware. However /System/States is not among the paths that the code can serialize. Therefore the only possibility is to implement the States-support to the firmware.

Easiest way is to do as follows:

1. In your python app call data subscription with "/System/States/3" (3 == DOUBLE_TAP)
2. Add a special *case* to the switch in onNotify which matches the localResourceId to the *WB_RES::LOCAL::SYSTEM_STATES_STATEID::LID*
3. In that handler, return the data the way you want. Easiest is to copy paste the "default" handler but replace the code between *getSbemLength()* & *writeToSbemBuffer(...)* calls with your own serialization code

*Full disclosure: I work for the Movesense team*